# How to change bundle environment when running the other ruby app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

```
#/home/user/a/test.rb
`/home/user/b/test.rb` # not found b's gems
```

Can not found b's gems when running b/test.rb in a/test.rb(running by user), and running test.rb under /home/user/b directly is OK.

```
#/home/user/a/test.rb
`sudo -u user /home/user/b/test.rb` # it's OK
```

And it is OK if running with `sudo -u user`.

How to find b's gems and run it except with `sudo -u user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for [`Bundler.with_clean_env`](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Shelling-out):

```
#/home/user/a/test.rb
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  # this assumes b/test.rb sets up Bundler itself
  `/home/user/b/test.rb`
end
```

There is also `clean_exec` and `clean_system` which wrap `system` and `exec`, which might be simpler in this case (since you don’t use the result of the backticks):

```
Bundler.clean_system '/home/user/b/test.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run in you terminal:

```
sudo gem list
```

and run:

```
gem list
```

to see the two list of gems

Comment: yep, run `gem list` in a/test.rb listing a's gems, so?

Comment: You need to run in on your terminal not in the script.
The "gem list" command display local gems installed in your system for the user who run it. Those gems are the only ones you can use in your script. I suggest to run "gem install name_of_the_gem_you_want" in you don't have it in that list.